# ECS service DNS isuue

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-ecs

I made a new ECS service in an existing cluster of services. I enabled the option of service connect & gave Discovery & DNS names ('analytics') along with listening port (8080) of my application. All the tasks (containers) are running on the same ec2 instance, including the new task which my new ECS service spawned.

The issue I am facing is- I cannot access new container from other containers as the they could not resolve the host name which I set (analytics).

Some of the things I tried:

1. I ran following inside one of previous containers:
   `curl -v analytics:8080` : `* Could not resolve host: analytics`
   `cat /etc/hosts` : Doesn't have host name 'analytics' (But has other host names defined for other services)
2. However, inside the new container I could find the new host name.
3. I tried restarting other containers, but it didn't work.
4. The containers can access the new container using its IP